# access sharepoint 2007 mySite links in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am developing an internal site in MVC to display some information from a share point 2007 site.

In share point, every user has a MySite and MyLinks on top nav.
I would need to access MyLinks and store them in a List<> to use them in my application.
How can I achieve this...

Note: I am new to sharepoint and have minimum idea on this.

Any help to put me in the correct direction would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Try Exploring `Microsoft.Sharepoint` dll. you may find many helpful classes in that. you can find this DLL at 12 hive.

Comment: I am exploring the sharepoint and found the service provided by sharepoint as http://sharepointsite/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx

Add also a service GetUserLinks Can I use this service to get the user links

Comment: I guess  Namespace `Microsoft.Sharepoint` should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont have any idea about MVC but something like this should work for you

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;


UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(ServerContext.Current);
UserProfile currentUser = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(true);
QuickLinkManager quickLinkManager = currentUser.QuickLinks;



foreach (QuickLink quickLink in quickLinkManager.GetItems())
{
    Console.WriteLine(quickLink.Url);
}
```

Dont Forget to add reference of `Microsoft.Sharepoint` and adding namespaces `Microsoft.Sharepoint` and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration`

**EDIT**
Add Reference of `Microsoft.Sharepoint` from following path `C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12`.

Comment: what should i must check
??